# Accessing a list within a razor page is requiring the use of First()

Tags: c#, razor

Ok So I have my view model as such

```
public  class ClubsViewModel
{
     public List<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
     public List<ClubDownloads> ClubDownloads { get; set; }
}
```

Which means that Can be many clubs parts of the view model,however when I go to my cshtml file I have to access as such.

```
@model IEnumerable<MSFSAddons.Dal.ViewModels.ClubsViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model.First().Clubs)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:gray">
            <img src="@item.Logo" width="100" height="100" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="ClubMembers" asp-route-id="@item.Id"> <span class="fa fa-users-cog fa-2x"></span> View Members</a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><span class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></span></a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></span></a> |

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Why must I use the the first() should I not just be able to access it via Model.Clubs what am i doing wrong here?

If you see here clubs is not accessable.

[image]

Comment: How are you declaring your model? I'm guessing you're declaring something like `@model IEnumerable<ClubsViewModel>`

Comment: @Magnetron I am sorry the code formatter left that out please see above.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is a collection of `ClubsViewModel`. Change it to a single unit:

```
@model MSFSAddons.Dal.ViewModels.ClubsViewModel
```

Comment: my god we do have our moments some times